# same helper for different template

Tags: meteor

as the [official meteor wiki about handlebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars) said:

> The only way to make a helper visible to multiple templates is to assign the same function to each one, or to declare a global helper.

I am using the [telescope](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope) to build an app and the problem is the value of "member since" in user-profile is missing like the follow image.
[image]
as the source code  in /client/views/users/user_profile.js
`Template.user_profile.createdAtFormatted = Template.user_item.createdAtFormatted;`
does not work well.

and here is the helper in /client/views/users/user_item.js `Template.user_item`

```
Template.user_item.helpers({
 createdAtFormatted: function(){
   return this.createdAt ? moment(this.createdAt).fromNow() : '–';
})
```

,when I change the code in  /client/views/users/user_profile.js like this:

```
Template.user_profile.createdAtFormatted = function() {
     return this.createdAt ? moment(this.createdAt).fromNow() : '–';
}
```

or make a Global helpers like this

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("createdAtFormatted", function(){
     return this.createdAt ? moment(this.createdAt).fromNow() : '–';
});
```

then, everything is ok like this
[image]

all I wonder is why the assignment `Template.user_profile.createdAtFormatted = Template.user_item.createdAtFormatted;` did not work as the way I or the author wish?

Answer (score 3):

This is probably because of the `helper` & a slight inconsistency in Meteor. I think the helpers were added later in Meteor.

Basically there are two ways to define helpers in meteor. One is:

```
Template.user_item.createdAtFormatted = function() {...}
```

and the below should do the same thing:

```
Template.user_item.helpers({
    'createdAtFormatted':function() {
    ...
    }
});
```

But the latter using `helpers` doesnt create a `Template.user_item.createdAtFormatted` definition so the above comes out as `undefined`. This is most likely a bug in meteor and should be fixed. I've opened a issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/886